# Is it possible to join strings in PL/SQL procedure in my sql statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

As the title suggests, I would like to know if it is possible to join the string in a select statement within a PL/SQL procedure.

For example, I have something like this

```
SELECT FCS.CATEGORY, 
       FCS.NUMBERS, 
       FCS.POINTS 
 WHERE FCS.OBJECT = 'T' 
   AND FCS.THIS_DB & strSelectedDB &
```

So, is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: what you are looking for is Dynamic SQL http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is a little confusing.  You can concatenate multiple strings using the || operator.  But you'd then you'd have to compare the concatenated string to something.  You can compare columns to local variables directly, though, i.e.

```
SELECT fcs.category,
       fcs.numbers,
       fcs.points
  FROM some_table fcs
 WHERE fcs.object  = 'T'
   AND fcs.this_db = strSelectedDB
```

assuming that strSelectedDB is a local variable in your PL/SQL block.